# 'Snips' pasted from clipboard into body of gmail message have broken “googleusercontent.com” after sending out the email

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

A user regularly sends emails by snipping to the clipboard and pasting it to the email body. They are not saving to a file and pasting that, but copying it straight to the clipboard and pasting.

Quite regularly now they've run into the issue where the images appear normal while composing the message, but when the message is sent some of them are now broken googleusercontent.com URLs that do not load. Even if the sender of the email goes to their sent items and views the email, they no longer can see them. The user is on Google Suite/Google for Business, Windows 10 Pro, Chrome 69.

Also it appears as though when you paste an image directly from clipboard to Gmail it creates a blob:mail.googl.com/hash-hash-hash URL, and something is going on after sending the email which results in a broken googleusercontent.com URL.

Any help or ideas to track down the issue would be appreciated!